# dynamically preparing camel to endpoint in 2.10 camel version

Tags: apache-camel

We are facing some issue in camel. Camel Version is : 2.10

Snippet Below :

```
  <dotry>
<camel:setHeader headerName="ExternalserviceAddress">
                <camel:simple>cxf:bean:ExternalService?address=${properties:${property.IncomingValue}_ServiceURL}&amp;dataFormat=PAYLOAD</camel:simple>
            </camel:setHeader>
             <camel:recipientList>
                <camel:header>ExternalserviceAddress</camel:header>
             </camel:recipientList> 

  <doCatch>
    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
 </doCatch>
 </doTry>
```

Here If I use *recipientList*  the exception is not handlng in local doCatch Block. Instead Exception is handling in Globally. Please suggest if any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<handled>
  <constant>true</constant>
</handled>
```

Now your exception can either be suppressed within this doTry block, or you can throw some other exception to parent route or whatever you want to do.

You can know more about *handled* here - http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html